# Stacking/Blending Predictive Models with More than Two Outcomes

Tags: predictive-models, model, stacking

I've been experimenting with stacking predictive models recently. I've mainly been focused on looking at making meta-models based off of predictive probabilities of smaller models while implementing coefficient weights (similar to the run-through in [this blog post](http://www.listendata.com/2015/08/ensemble-learning-stacking-blending.html)).

This method is pretty simple with a binary outcome, but was wondering how it would be implemented with something like a three class outcome. Any suggestions on other stacking methods would be great